# Core 2.0 navbar banner covering page content on mobile device

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-core, mobile

I created a simple core 2.0 web application but i'm having issues getting the content to display on a mobile device.

This is an image of the site when i hold the device vertical:
[image]

This is an image when i hold the device vertical and scroll down:
[image]

When i hold the device sideways, the message also appears:
[image]

For the most part i used the default settings after creating the project in Visual Studio 2017.
This is the markup in _Layout.cshtml:

```
<div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top text-center vcenter " style="font-size:80px; font-weight:bolder;color:white;">
            The                 
        </nav>
</div>
```

Here's the markup for the page that contains the message:

```
<div class="row" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
    @if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.message))
    {
        <div class="row col-md-10 text-center" id="divMessage" 
          style="background-color:white;">
          @Model.message
        </div>
}
</div>
```

Here is the css for the navbar:

```
   .navbar {
        position: fixed;
        min-height: 100px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        min-width: 100%;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        color: white;
    }
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar {
        border-radius: 4px;
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top {
        position: relative;
        top: auto;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        max-height: none;
    }
    body {
        margin: 0;
    }
}
```

Here is the css for the body:

```
    body {
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.body-content {
    padding-top: 110px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

Can someone please help me fix the vertical view of the site on a mobile device so that body content does not get hidden underneath the navbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a fixed header and its text is wrapping on mobile. Therefore, the normal top padding you're applying to the content to push it below the header is insufficient on mobile. You'll need to utilize media query breakpoints to change either the font-size in the header (so it doesn't wrap) and/or adjust the top padding to compensate for the wrapping.

```
.body-content {
    padding-top: 210px;
}

@media (min-width: 480px) {
    .body-content {
        padding-top: 110px;
    }
}
```

This might look a little backwards, but your base style should be what's required on mobile, and then you specify break points from there, reducing the padding once you hit a width that no longer wraps the heading text. I just plopped in `480px`, but you'll need to test to see what the actual width is for you.